# Error:Emulator: OpenGL backend 'angle' without OpenGL ES 1.x library detected. Using GLESv2 only

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have search the forum and cant find exact answer for these.

Every time I compile and run the app. There is an error

> Emulator: OpenGL backend 'angle' without OpenGL ES 1.x library
>   detected. Using GLESv2 only.

However, everything still run smoothly, and thus I didn't bother.

So, what is the correct approach to this?

1. To update the library.
2. To ignore it since it is just outdated but usable.
3. What are the benefit of updating

Refer
[Android OpenGL ES 2.0 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941016/android-opengl-es-2-0-emulator)

I found out that there are a few questions like this remain unanswered. Thus Anyone please give a suggestion so other will know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Angle](https://github.com/google/angle) is an open-source project that implements OpenGLES over DirectX/Desktop OpenGL. That is, it takes OpenGLES commands, and converts them to something that can run easily on desktop machines.

It's likely that the Android emulator would use a technology like Angle to convert your project's OpenGLES commands and possibly the Android OS OpenGLES commands to DirectX/Desktop OpenGL.

The error is telling you that the Angle library lacks the OpenGLES 1.x component. I'm not sure if it's a normal situation or not - if it is an error, it's a problem with the emulator, not with your code. If everything appears to be working correctly then I wouldn't worry about it.  Most likely the emulated OS and your project are using OpenGLES 2 or 3, or if you are using OpenGLES 1.x, then perhaps there's a compatibility layer that implements OpenGLES 1.x over OpenGLES 2 before anything gets passed to Angle.

Comment: Meaning we can actually ignore it if everything works out?

Comment: Yeah, safe to ignore I think.

Comment: Thanks for the answer